# How to set itemize style in AnnArbor theme as a ball?

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize, latex3

For example, the slide below the itemize is shaped like a ball with the number inserted inside. While the sub items are only numbers, but in blue color.

[image]

On the slide below, however, the itemize are numbers as well as the sub items, but I would like to get the pattern from the slide above, i.e., itemize in the shape of a ball with the number inside. I would also like to keep the color of themecolor Beaver, i.e. the red color in the itemize and sub itemizes.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem, enumerate}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{enumerate}[label = \arabic*.]
         \item {\bf Amostra:} 
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this MWE related to the two screenshots?

Comment: Do you want a red ball and red numbers in your enumerate environment?

Comment: Hi @leandriis, Only the ball in red, the number can be white.

Comment: I have edited my answer to also reflect that.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! Thank you, @leandriis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `enumerate` or `enumitem` with `beamer`. You can instead use appropriate `\setbeamertemplate` commands to change the appearence of the numbers:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, xcolor = {divpsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=red!80!black} %<---- color of ball
\setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=red!80!black} %<--- color of number in second level

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[ball] %<---- appearence of number in first level
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel} %<---- appearence of number in second level


\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{enumerate}
         \item \textbf{Amostra:} some item text here
           \begin{enumerate}
           \item more items here
           \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```